# Partitioning in DocumentDB

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

I'm wondering about the `partitionkey` in a partitioned `DocumentDB` collection in the following scenario:

1. Each document `C` in the collection contains 2 fields: `a` and `b`
2. It's necessary fast lookups for document `C` using both fields `a` and `b` as criteria for the lookups(using them at the sql query `where` clause).

I believe is necessary somehow specify both fields to accomplish the goal 2. Is there any way I can specify both fields `a` and `b` as partition keys for my collection?

If not, is there any alternative solution?

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways to do this:

- Pick either `a` or `b`(receiver) as the partition key. Since DocumentDB automatically indexes all properties, queries will be executed against a single partition.
- Create a new property that's the concatenated value of `a` and `b` (e.g. `from:a@b.com;to:c@d.com` and use that as the partition key. Then when performing queries, include the new property as a filter in your queries.

The second approach will be more efficient than the first for query by both `a` and `b`. If you have a mix of queries with just `a` or both (`a` and `b`), then the first approach is better as both queries will be against a single partition.

But as others mentioned, you will have low latency query responses with either approach, or if you even picked a different partition key like transaction ID. But the approaches above will be the most optimal for a query workload that filters on `a` and `b`.

Answer (score 1):

I think you may have two notions mixed up here - Partitioning and Indexing.

In order to support fast retrievals using both a and b as criteria, you need to have your documents indexed on those fields. Luckily, DocumentDB already indexes for you, so you get fast performance. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/documentdb/documentdb-indexing

Partitioning is a way to split your data, if you have a lot of it, over multiple collections, in order to deal with data going over the single collection limit. When you specify a partition key, documents with the same key will go to the same collection. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/documentdb/documentdb-partition-data

So what logic should you consider when picking a partition key? As a rule of thumb, you want documents that come up together in your queries to be found in the same collection. So for example, if you do a lot of queries that return all documents for a given userId, you may want to partition by user id.

Comment: thank you for the clarification. In my case the document C is a transaction and field a is the sender id of a transaction and field b is the receiver id of that transaction. I'd like to lookup for all transactions a sent to b. I'm using as partition key the transaction id itself.

Comment: Are you sure you need to partition? What size data are you dealing with? The answer is still the same though - docdb will do an efficient search over all partitions with your query, and then combine the results.

Comment: is like 300G of transaction data. I did a test and retrieved 5k of transactions from a to b in almost 1 minute waiting to retrieve this set of transactions.

Comment: So a few suggestions - 1. Check the part in the partitioning link above about querying multiple partitions, and doing so in parallel. 2. Consider having another collection keeping a map between user and transaction id, if that makes sense in your case. 3. If you want to optimize for this type of query, why not use the sender id as the partition key?

Comment: thanks one more time for the suggestions Eran. I partitioned by the transaction id because there is another scenario where is desirable to lookup by the transaction id itself.

Comment: I suggest moving this discussion to chat.stackoverflow.com and not continue in comments (as this isn't the place for such discussion).